Firefox browser from Ubuntu 24.04 is not able connect to the server after connected to the VPN
I have local Ubuntu 24.04 VM that are having issue to open webpage on Firefox browser after connected to the VPN. I tried using Chrome browser and it is working fine with the VPN. Did anyone are having similar issues as me? I have tried the methods provided from Firefox on the VM but the issue is still persist (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/server-not-found-connection-problem#w_firefox-cannot-load-websites-but-other-browsers-can).
Screenshot of the error of Firefox while connected to the VPN

Did you install firefox from App Center?

in FF, you may need to set network to manual settings.

@amar The firefox is the default version when I installed the Ubuntu OS, but I did tried to uninstall the Firefox and install it from App Center.

If it is still from App Center go into Settings, Apps, Firefox and enable Read Access to Network Settings, I am not sure it will help but you can try .
